# Plotly histogram labels printed horizontally

Tags: python-3.x, plotly

I have some value which are too small but i need to print them. The ideal would be to print out of the bar by matching the color. Is it possible to do?
By incrementing the font, the label are still printed horizontally

[image]

Look for the uppest value in the first bar (the horizontal 8) and the value 5 and 7 in the lowest part of the second bar.

```
fig = go.Figure()
fig = px.histogram(dfT_plot, x='Model', y='value', color='Class',
                    text_auto='',
                    color_discrete_sequence=["rgb(44, 160, 44)",  "#FFFF00","lightgreen", "crimson", "#800000", "orange",],
                    category_orders=dict(Class=["1","2","3","4", "5", "6"])) \
        .update_layout(
                    title={
                            "text": 'Results',
                            "font": dict(size=23),
                            "x": 0.5
                          },
                    yaxis_title="Y",
                    xaxis_title="X",) \
        .update_xaxes(categoryorder="total ascending") \
        .update_yaxes(range=[270, 400])
fig.add_hline(y=311, line_color='black', line_width=1)
fig.update_traces(
                    xbins=dict(size=0.1))  # bins used for histogram)
fig.update_layout(
    autosize=False,
    width=1000,
    height=500,
    yaxis=dict(titlefont=dict(size=20)),
    xaxis=dict(titlefont=dict(size=20)),
    uniformtext_minsize=15, uniformtext_mode='show'
    )
```